# Create Nested Serialier Multi Objects in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm finding a solution which create Nested Serialier Multi Objects in Django Rest Framework?

I have 2 models: Product and Photo (Photo is a model which store all photos of Products). This serializer I created in order to create a Product & upload all image of this products:

```
class PhotoUpdateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = [
            'image'
        ]

class ProductCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    photos = ProductPhotosSerializer(many=True, write_only=True, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'id',
            'user',
            'name',
            'photos'
        ]
```

**My viewsets:**

```
class ProductCreateAPIView(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductCreateSerializer
    def create_product(self, request):
        newProduct = Product.objects.create(
           user = User.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('user')),
           name = request.POST.get('name', '')
        )
        newPhotos = Photo.objects.create(
           product = newProduct.id,
           image = request.POST.get('photos.image', '')
        )
        serializer = ProductCreateSerializer(newProduct, context={"request": request})
        return Response(serializer.data, status=200)
```

Error: `Request.POST has no photos.image`

When I print(request.POST), use POSTMAN like this picture:

[image: image of the web interface]

It prints: `{u'user': [u'2']}>`. No photos POST?

Comment: The error you are showing her that means its missing `photos.image` when you sending request from the frontend. Make sure your form working fine to upload the image and it is sending to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

try :       `image = request.data.get('image')`

Normally what I would do is base 64 encode the image at the source and decode it at the view.